# Do I need Impressum for a website while freelancing in Germany?

Tags: germany, freelance

I will start my part-time freelance activity in Germany as a software engineer (data scientist is my profession). I would like to create my own website where I will advertise my services but not selling any products there. The purpose of the site is my advertise myself and skills digitaly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you’ll need to indicate all details as per [§ 5 TMG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/tmg/__5.html).
Your site is a (vital) component in generating income, hence the nature of your site is businesslike (*geschäftsmäßig*).

Merely posting your résumé *without* advertising your rates, on the hand, could be deemed a *private‑only* matter (so it does not necessitate an imprint).
*Finding* employment for yourself is not “running a business”.

If you are unsure whether your site’s contents already meet the threshold of *geschäftsmäßig*, err for including an imprint.
The fines are up to € 50,000, § 11 Ⅱ № 2, Ⅲ TMG.

<sup>PS:
Weren’t you able to answer question with an adequate search engine query?</sup>